# How can I download files, and process them only if some file does not exist?

Tags: bash, file, wget, polling, exists

_why is back, and of course leaving spooled messages on his webserver. I'd like to periodically poll his site, check for new spools, and if they don't exist already, convert them to PDF.

I have the poll & conversion process down, using https://github.com/bsandrow/_why-spool. I modified one block in the scraping script to look like this:

```
echo "Downloading PCL files..."
spool_urls | while read spool_entry; do
    file="$(spool_file "$spool_entry")"
    echo "  $file"

    if [ ! -f "/home/max/_why-spool/build/$file.pdf" ]
    then
        echo "/home/max/_why-spool/build/$file.pdf does not exist" >> /home/max/why_log.txt
        wget -q -O "src/$file" "$spool_entry"
    fi
done
```

This is supposed to check if `$file`.pdf exists. Even though it does exist, the `if` fails, and downloads the spool anyway. How can I fix this?

EDIT: Look. Results of an `ls` —

```
max build $ ls /home/max/_why-spool/build/
ACCOUNTS.pdf  BURN.pdf        FAREWELL.pdf  FLIPPED.pdf  HELLOYES.pdf  JUXT.pdf    OUTRAGE.pdf  REALITY.pdf  SACRED.pdf    STINKS.pdf  WHATSUPDOC.pdf
AMANDA.pdf    CORRUPTION.pdf  FIGHTS.pdf    FRIGHTS.pdf  IMPERSON.pdf  LEAPS.pdf   PIRATEO.pdf  RECEIPT.pdf  SEAWATER.pdf  TORN.pdf    YOUGETIT.pdf
BIBLICAL.pdf  EYES.pdf        FIRELESS.pdf  GAIMAN.pdf   ITISUS.pdf    LOOKUP.pdf  READING.pdf  REVERSE.pdf  SENSORED.pdf  TRIALS.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate this. I deleted some files to test it, and the `if` passes when it should pass. Perhaps you can try one of more of these

- use double brackets `[[`
- move the exclamation before the bracket
- use `-a`
- use `-e`
- use `$HOME`

```
$ ls /home/Steven/_why-spool/build/
ACCOUNTS.pdf  GINGERBREAD.pdf  PROFESSORS.pdf  SACRED.pdf    STINKS.pdf
CLOWNS.pdf    HO.pdf           RECEIPT.pdf     SEAWATER.pdf

$ scrape
Downloading PCL files...
  STINKS
  GAIMAN
/home/Steven/_why-spool/build/GAIMAN.pdf does not exist
  ACCOUNTS
  RECEIPT
  SEAWATER
  HELLOYES
/home/Steven/_why-spool/build/HELLOYES.pdf does not exist
  SACRED
  CLOWNS
  BLANK
/home/Steven/_why-spool/build/BLANK.pdf does not exist
  HO
  GINGERBREAD
  PROFESSORS
```

Comment: That's so strange :( I eventually fixed it by dropping quotes but... weird.